# Plotting some figure simultaneously with changing their names in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-files

I use the following code for plotting and saving 8 figures. This code does not show all 8 figures in one time. How to do that? because now we should close one figure and another one appears.

and how can change the name and title of figure once for each figure using the values of data in `data` file?
for example `Fig1: ng = 100`, `Fig2: ng = 250` and so on. `100` and `250` are the data inside the datafile.

Thank you

```
row, uf, ng, Tg = np.genfromtxt('texdata.txt',unpack=True)
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
for x in range(len(ng)):
    for xx in range(1,819):
            ET_list=[]
            z_list=[]
            for z in np.arange(1,7):
                    Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                    Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                    lim = Ju - Jl
                    if lim > 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if Ju<7:
                            ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, 100, 1e9, 1, ng[x], 0, Tg[x], 1))
                            z_list.append(z)                  
                            plt.plot(z_list, ET_list))
                        else:
                            pass
    ax1.title.set_text('Fig 1: ng = 100 ')  # we need to change this value for each figure and number of the figure
    plt.savefig('Fig1:T_j.png') # number of the figure should change
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f string` formatting:

```
ax1.title.set_text(f'Fig {x}: TG = {Tg[x]}, ng = {ng[x]} ')
plt.savefig(f'Fig1:T_{x}.png')
```

*Assuming `ng` and `x` are the values you want to utilize.*

Comment: and this way put the values of `Tg[x]` and `ng[x]` in the title?

Comment: I put them, but it shows all the value of `ng` in one plot and no for other plots. And My first question was about having all 8 plots in one time.

Comment: I did what you are updating, but it just works for first plot. Im confused how to do all plot in one time with this code together

Comment: F strings will insert any variable into the string. Which variable of yours is dynamic? Put that in the for loop and your names will be corrected.

Comment: One thing is misunderstood. First I should do plots simultaneously. because in this current code of mine, I cannot plot 8 plots in one time.

Comment: I have to close one to see another one

Comment: Consider clarifying in your Q above @MaY

Comment: in my code I should have 8 plots. when I run this code I have a plot, when I close it, another one appears unill the 8th plot. But I should have 8plots in once

Comment: Consider utilizing subplots.

Comment: I appreciate if you could help me, because I have never used python plot before. and in these days I got stuck into in alot

Comment: I'm sorry, your Q is too confusing at this point. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.